# How do I create the "Gnome-Desktop-Item-Edit" program's launch icon with root privileges and more?

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I personally dont prefer running commands in terminal to achieve a task and prefer apps to execute the job.

Creating launcher for apps is one such command where I prefer the gnome-desktop-item-edit application for creating launchers. If the gnome package is installed, just searching "create launcher" opens the app. I have created launchers for windows app on wine installation using create launcher

But, it doesnt serve any purpose, because for starters the application cannot create launchers for various apps without root permission and the location where the apps have to be created.

Usually the launcher apps with root permission can be created at /usr/share/applications and without root permission at /.local/share/applications. I dont prefer the latter location as it is vulnerable to deletion.

Hence, in order to create the launchers through gnome with root, everytime I am forced to open this through terminal using the below command!

**`$ sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications --create-new`**

I **dont want** to open terminal everytime I want to create an application launcher on unity!

I am able to lock the "Create Launcher" App in the Launcher, but not with root privileges

So I want to be able to create the "Create Launcher" app shortcut on unity with default root privileges and for the app to create the launchers at usr/share/applications by default!

Please help!

P.S. I dont have enough rep points to add screenshots to help with the question!

Comment: if you want to add screenshots post the links and we will provide on editing your question

Comment: @AlexGreg here are the screenshots you requested.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/lgFQA.jpg
http://i.stack.imgur.com/45eN1.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/eeEOC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom "Create Launcher"..open the terminal and type `sudo "gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications --create-new"`

in the launcher creation put some name like `Custom Launcher Creation` and in the command put

```
gksudo "gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications --create-new"
```

now search this launcher and add it to favorites on your left bar

every time you will launch it it will ask you the sudo password like gparted for example. In this way you won't need the terminal any more

Comment: but you won't access the terminal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, if this is the command that I would need to key into terminal everytime to access "Create Launcher", then that isnt of much help. I want to avoid accessing the terminal altogether

Comment: Apologies in advance. I should have clarified this, but I am a novice at using Ubuntu and terminal based commands. The command that you suggested opens "Create Launcher" again but with the password outside terminal like in gparted as you suggested. But I have a shortcut/launcher of the "Create Launcher" App. Are you suggesting that I create a launcher for "Create Launcher" using "Create Launcher itself?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope It clarifies the solution

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked and helped a lot!

But just to correct the answer, in case others are looking at finding a solution for the same problem as mine. Key in `gksudo "gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications --create-new"` after opening the terminal. When you are prompted for a password, the "Create Launcher" app opens. Then enter your desirable name for the app. Choose your own icon if you want to. In the command section, enter `sudo "gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications --create-new"`. Hit the OK Button. Open usr/share/applications to find ur shortcut there!